# Unable to add top and centerX constraints programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

```
let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "Loading"))
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 200)
imageView.center = self.view.center
self.view.addSubview(imageView)

let xConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
let verticalSpace = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 100)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([xConstraint, verticalSpace])

self.rotate(imageView: imageView, aCircleTime: 1)


let titleLabel = UILabel()
titleLabel.text = "Loading picker route"
titleLabel.textAlignment = .center
self.view.addSubview(imageView)


NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: self.view.frame.size.width).isActive = true
NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 44).isActive = true
NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: imageView , attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: imageView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 100).isActive = true
```

Crash at last two lines with below report

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException',
> reason: 'Unable to activate constraint with anchors
> <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x2839a8540 "UILabel:0x115d12580.top"> and
> <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x2839fc000 "UIImageView:0x115d10730.bottom">
> because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its
> anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's
> illegal.'

Comment: You don't add `titleLabel` to the view, you're adding `imageView` again.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the the label

```
titleLabel.textAlignment = .center
self.view.addSubview(titleLabel)
```

plus these 2 lines

```
imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

**Edit:**

```
let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "Loading"))
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 200)
imageView.center = self.view.center
self.view.addSubview(imageView)

let xConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
let verticalSpace = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 100)
let width = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 200)
let height =  NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 200)

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([xConstraint, verticalSpace,width,height])

self.rotate(imageView: imageView, aCircleTime: 1)

let titleLabel = UILabel()
titleLabel.text = "Loading picker route"
titleLabel.textAlignment = .center

self.view.addSubview(titleLabel)
 

imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false


NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: self.view.frame.size.width).isActive = true
NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 44).isActive = true
NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: imageView , attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: imageView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 100).isActive = true
```

Comment: did you try the code i added in question?

Comment: I tested the edit, it works well : by centering horizontally and vertically the imageView and giving it width and height, there's no need then to add top/bottom anchors.